# Why Android App showing blank screen when coming out of an App with back button React Native Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am working on React Native Application and integrated react-native-navigation package for navigation inside app, [link of package](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)

Android App got stuck and show blank screen. This happens if I am closing app using back button in case of Android app. At the end I have a listing screen, after reopen the application it shows blank screen because it's not calling `Navigation.registerComponent` again, it might be destroying app when closed using back button.
This is a code inside my index.js::

```
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";
import App from './src/app';

Navigation.registerComponent("appName", () => App);
```

Killing the app and restarting would fix the stuck on splash screen issue. But shouldn't be stuck in the first place. Just an issue when closing through back button.

Does anyone have a fix for this? Please suggest how can I handle and call my `Navigation.registerComponent` once again after closing app using back button.

**Environment**

- React Native Navigation version: 2.12.0
- React Native version: 0.58
- Platform(s) : Android only

Comment: Why you don't use the new version of `react-navigation`?

Comment: @ArchanaSharma I am having the same problem did you solved this problem?

Comment: @Ahtesham Shah please check my answer below, it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this you need to make modification inside react-native-navigation package. Open NavigationActivity.java file and replace below code with new one:

Replace this code:

```
@Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        if (!navigator.handleBack(new CommandListenerAdapter())) {
         super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

With this one:

```
@Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        if (!navigator.handleBack(new CommandListenerAdapter())) {
          this.moveTaskToBack(true);
         //super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

After saving your changes check on android device.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply I will definitely try it.

Comment: you just disable/tweak the back button functionality. The app may still stuck on the white screen after android optimize your phone memory.